# In Ruby, how can I find cities within range from a whitelist of cities?

Tags: ruby, geolocation

I have a whitelist of cities. I have a user who has specified their location. I want to find out which of those cities is within a 50 mile radius of the user.

What steps do I need to take in order to get this information? Maybe there's some geocoding gems that help with this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem. It will provide you [distance calculation methods](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#distance-and-bearing).

Here is a quick example to show you how you can proceed:

```
require 'geocoder'

cities = %w( Paris Tokyo Berlin New-York )
geocoded_cities = cities.map{ |city| Geocoder.search( city ).first }

user_city = "London"
geocoded_user_city = Geocoder.search( user_city ).first

close_cities = geocoded_cities.select do |city|
  Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between( city.coordinates, geocoded_user_city.coordinates, { units: :mi } ) < 800
end
```